# Batch replacing white background with a colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, batch-processing

I need to batch replace the white background on several thousand images. Is there a better way of doing this aside from setting up an action, selecting the white background and filling in colour?

Comment: Look up Droplets in your Adobe Manual.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are "No" unless all the images contain the same subject matter. It's nearly impossible to batch remove a background if the edges of the subject matter are different.

That is unless you've got some standardized off-color background color, like a green screen which will *never* actually be in the image subject matter itself.

Comment: I thought as much :( Thank you for your help!